# What is micronaut-bom?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, micronaut

While I worked on a Micronaut project und tried to solve some problems, like dynamic versioning of dependencies and creating a multi module micronaut project with Gradle. I found in some code examples of the `build.gradle` this dependency:

```
annotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:2.0.0")
```

But I could not find any official documentation referring to it. What does it do? Can it help me with versioning my dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Micronaut BOM (Bill Of Material, [further reading](https://dzone.com/articles/the-bill-of-materials-in-maven)) declares all the framework dependencies of a specific Micronaut release. In your example it is the BOM of Micronaut release 2.0.0.

By declaring the as a `platform` dependency you don't have to worry about Micronaut about the versions of supported JARs, since they already are defined in the BOM.

For example if you decide to use the Caffeine Cache with Micronaut you simply declare it as a dependency but omit the version number.

```
dependencies {
   implementation("io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-caffeine")
}
```

That way you make sure that you are using well tested dependencies with your Micronaut release.

**why is it an `annotationProcessor?**

An update since the following question came up.

> Uuh. Nice. So its a collection of dependencies with the best working versions for my specific micronaut version? Cool. And why is it a annotationProcessor?

`annotationProcessor` is Gradle related and is called a dependency configuration. When using the `java` Gradle plugin you have out of the box dependency configurations such as `implementation` or `api`.

With a dependency configuration you configure the dependencies for e.g. an annotation processor by using the configuration `annotationProcessor`. `implementation` is used for your compile time dependencies. And if you want to expose the dependencies to other modules that use your module you might want to use `api` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: Uuh. Nice. So its a collection of dependencies with the best working versions for my specific micronaut version? Cool. And why is it a annotationProcessor?